What could explain that small planes near an airport are perceived as harassing homeowners?
My friend lives near a smaller busy airport and told me she's getting the feeling that pilots of small propeller planes are purposely flying very fast and loud around her neighborhood sometimes 4 of them at a time. She says they start as early as 6am and go as late as 12 midnight.
I've been been at her home when this has happened and some of the planes are really loud. Sometimes they do this for hours at a time. Other pilots fly over and are not nearly as loud and you don't even notice them unless you happen to look up and see them.

Knowing some tail numbers would help us see if the planes are flying in normal boring ways or if there’s truth to this.

6am to 12pm sounds more like the schedule of a relatively big hub than a small GA airfield. I'd check with the local authorities it there's a time (and noise) limitation in force.

@sophit I'm not sure about OP's location, but many GA airports in the U.S. are not small and few (even of the small ones) have time restrictions or noise restrictions that have significant applications to small, propeller-driven aircraft. Some U.S. GA airports can actually have more flight operations than some airline hubs. Van Nuys airport (in Los Angeles) has had as many as 600,000 annual flight operations in the past. To put this into perspective, London-Heathrow had 454,000 last year.

I would also note that it is exceedingly unlikely that any aircraft (propeller-driven or otherwise) is flying fast (for their airplane) near an airport. Takeoff and landing and typically the slowest parts of a flight and both climb-out and final approach have particular (and relatively slow) speeds that pilots will always fly during those phases of flight.

I have a coworker who's learning to fly right now and he's doing the lessons early in the morning before work, because it's cheaper and convenient for traffic heading to work. So 6am flights will not be unusual if there's a flight school.

@reirab "Prior to May 2011, […] numbers included flights that transitioned into VNY airspace, including flights to Burbank. As of May 2011, VNY no longer includes [these], and instead only reports actual takeoffs and landings at VNY." But it's still an impressive number.

@Bergi Right, but, if you look at the year where that transition happened, it only dropped the number by about 40,000, so still probably a good 550+k daily flight operations at the peak.

@Eugene Night flying is also relatively common if there are flight training operations because night flying is a required part of flight training. Also, there doesn't need to be an actual flight school in order to have flight training operations. CFIs can do flight training at nearly any airport, other than a few of the busiest ones. The airports I flew out of when doing flight training are relatively small GA fields that don't have any formal flight school. At least here in TN, flight training seems to be common at most public GA airports.

There is another neighbor who has videos posted on Facebook and the airport location. The airport is Oakland County International Airport in Waterford Michigan. https://www.facebook.com/groups/857372182865064/

Person buys/rents home near a busy airport. Sometime later, person is annoyed airplanes are flying in and out of said busy airport. Amazing...

It's not intentional. Small airports have a traffic pattern -- think of a rectangle where one of the long ends is the runway. Airplanes fly this pattern when landing, and student or private pilots will frequently fly circuits of this pattern to get additional practice landing. As you noted, sometimes several airplanes will do this at a time.

Traffic Pattern (image from the FAA Airplane Flying Handbook)
Airplanes make more noise when they're climbing than when they're descending. If your friend's neighborhood is beyond one end of the runway, some of the time airplanes will overfly the neighborhood while they're taking off. Which direction airplanes take off is influenced by which direction the wind is blowing. They're not being loud over your friend's neighborhood out of spite, they're being loud because the wind is coming from the west rather than the east (for example).
Additionally, some airplanes are simply louder than others.
Takeoff and landing are the most demanding phases of flight. A pilot is not going to spend the mental energy intentionally bothering the people who live near the airport (for what reason?). They're focusing on getting off the ground or back on the ground safely and efficiently.
If this small airport has a flight school, perhaps your friend could inquire about a "discovery flight", to see what flying entails. She could converse with an instructor about planes overflying her neighborhood to see what they're doing there.

Well, I think it is a truism that noisy things closer to you are noisier yet, and aircraft at lower heights landing and taking off will sound louder to the neighborhoods nearest the ends of the runways. For practice and learning and staying current pilots will often fly circuits and touch and goes (rapid landing/takeoffs) no doubt from time to time this can become irritating.

A small training plane costs at least $120 per hour to rent, so most pilots are not going to waste time in the air just making noise to piss people off.
Now if the airport in question hosts a flight school, then the student pilots taking lessons there will make landings and takeoffs over and over all day long, flying the same pattern around and around again, until they get proficient.
Even after they obtain their licenses, they will still spend hours at a time doing nothing but takeoffs and landings - which are called "touch & go's" because as soon as the plane's wheels are rolling on the runway, the pilot revs up the engine and does a takeoff without even coming to a halt, to get the most possible landings and takeoffs per hour of plane rental time.

Have pilots intentionally looked to overfly a specific property? Almost undoubtedly - and I'd suggest probably routinely in multiple places around the world.
Was it done with harassment in mind? possibly, but probably rarely.

One notable example in the UK is a popular TV personality, turned farmer, Jeremy Clarkson.
He has on many occasions reported light aircraft pilots intentionally (in his opinion) flying low over his farm in the Cotswolds. This has lead to news stories in the national press.

One of the pilots claimed to investigators at the UK Airprox Board that he believed the person flying the other aircraft "was looking to manoeuvre over a noteworthy property" when the near-miss incident occurred.


Over the weekend, the presenter took to Twitter to share his annoyance at someone flying over his farm.
Jeremy penned: “Quick message to the chap flying in circles 500 feet above my house: f*** off.”
Fan @davroschief1 then responded to the star about the issue.
They penned: “It’s legal Jeremy (unfortunately).”
The petrolhead then hit back: “It’s legal. But selfish.”


Oh the irony of Clarkson being annoyed by what someone else is doing

He could use the Welsh approach to deterring aircraft: https://www.targeta.co.uk/wheretogo.htm

Most pilots I know, including myself, don't want to annoy the community due to the potential of the airport ending up closing and being sold to a developer for housing or a mall.  Some airports have published "noise abatement procedures", which are specific instructions to avoid noise-sensitive areas.  You can contact the local FAA FSDO office to inquire about this:
https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo
See also: https://www.faa.gov/faq/what-noise-abatement-procedure
